# Enviar fichero JSON mediante POST a una URL

Tags: json, http

¿Cómo se puede mandar un fichero JSON mediante el método POST y protocolo HTTP a una determinada URL?

Éste es el contenido del fichero JSON:

```json
{
"MODELO": "111",
"EJERCICIO": "2020",
"PERIODO": "01",
"NRC": "1110000000000000000000",
"IDI": "ES",
"F01": "…",
"FIR": "FirmaBasica",
"FIRNIF": "89890001K",
"FIRNOMBRE": "USUARIO PRUEBA"
}
```

URL: https://www1.agenciatributaria.gob.es/wlpl/PFTW-PICW/PresBasicaDos

Os agradeceríamos inmensamente vuestra colaboración, ya que nosotros programamos en Visual Studio, lenguaje Visual Basic, y nos es muy complicado ahora mismo por la premura entregar una solución a nuestros clientes.

Gracias anticipadas.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). O, al menos, indicar en qué lenguaje de programación tenéis que realizar la petición HTTP y/o en qué sistema operativo.

Comment: Quieres un código en VB que suba ese JSON? es eso?

Comment: @Yussef, habrá que esperar a saber exactamente qué problema tiene y en qué sistema operativo o lenguaje de programación desea hacer lo que necesita. Probablemente le venga bien que sea en VB, pero quizá también necesite que se envíen todos los archivos JSON que va almacenando en un directorio, o quién sabe... pero sin código... no somos ni sus empleados ni una ONG de desarrollo :)

Comment: Voto el cierre de la pregunta por no poder reproducir el problema ni proporcionar MCVE.

Comment: Puedes usar una herramienta de línea de comandos como `curl`. Por ejemplo: `curl -X POST https://www1.agenciatributaria.gob.es/wlpl/PFTW-PICW/PresBasicaDos   -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"MODELO": "111", "EJERCICIO": "2020", "PERIODO": "01", "NRC": 
 1110000000000000000000", "IDI": "ES", "F01": "…", "FIR": "FirmaBasica", "FIRNIF": "89890001K", "FIRNOMBRE": "USUARIO PRUEBA" }'`

Comment: @abulafia, gracias por el aporte, pero por desgracia eso no funcionará porque la página de destino usa autenticación basada en certificado de cliente por lo que, como mínimo, necesitarás agregar el parámetro `--cert <certificado>[:contraseña]`. Pero, como estamos preguntando, quizá no pueda hacer uso de `curl` si, por ejemplo, usa una versión Windows Server que no lleve dicha herramienta o, por ejemplo, si necesita implementarlo dentro de su aplicación. Mejor esperar a que nos proporcionen más datos acerca de la necesidad.